# How to extract coordinates from where the variable meets a criterion for a netCDF dataset with Python and xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a xarray DataArray object `da_criteria_daily` where are generated from a netCDF file.

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 365, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(365, 106, 193), dtype=bool, chunksize=(1, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
```

It's a daily data over a year for a geographic extent. The variable is a Boolean type.

I would like to get all coordinates (latitude, longitude) values for a particular date where the variable is True.

```
new_da = da_criteria_daily.where(da_criteria_daily==True, drop=True)
print(new_da)
```

I got:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 161, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(161, 106, 193), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
```

Are you any functions with xarray.DataArray that can be used to retrieve coordinates from variables?

Comment: You should show what you've tried and what isn't working. As it stands, you are asking others to do work for you.

Comment: @jhamman. thanks I have tried to add as much as I could. But I don't know where to go any further from here.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with numpy this way:

```
numpy.argwhere(numpy.array(da_criteria_daily))
```

`numpy.argwhere()` gives you the indexes of the non-zero (True) elements. Then you can use the longitude, latitude and time coord arrays to get the real values.

Using xarray's `.where()` will only replace the values that do not meet the condition with nans, that is, your False values will now be nans. I don't know of any method of xarray to get the coordinates of certain values. It would definitively be useful but I guess no one has developed it yet.